# Prevent saving page as with nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, server, client

I am developing a project with NextJs. The project is an editor application. That's why I want the page(editor) not to work when they save the page differently. For example Youtube, Instagram etc. applications do not work when the page is saved as. How do they do this? And what approach should I take ?

The editor should not work when the page is saved as different. So I can use this project commercially.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube and Instagram work fine after saving, you just need a server to serve the files

**Nothing you can do to prevent this**

Comment: This is a commercial project .can't I follow any approach ?

Comment: Every file on your website is accessible through the dev tools anyway. Store your important things on the backend

Comment: All elements in the project have events and their events are on the frontend. At least I want it not to work when the page is saved differently.